# Example of subsets in plane with continuous bijective mapping between them

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

The question is from [C. Pugh's Real Analysis](https://books.google.ca/books?id=2NVJCgAAQBAJ&pg=PA129&lpg=PA129&dq=Construct%20nonhomeomorphic%20connected,%20closed%20subsets%20for%20which%20there%20exists%20continuous%20bijections.&source=bl&ots=ZN6O738GSa&sig=uAhayEqyfwiqfDCD3lhrZpKbgWE&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiHz83OnszKAhUGXR4KHT5LDq0Q6AEIKjAC#v=onepage&q=Construct%20nonhomeomorphic%20connected%2C%20closed%20subsets%20for%20which%20there%20exists%20continuous%20bijections.&f=false): Construct nonhomeomorphic connected, closed subsets A, B $\subset$ $\mathbb{R}^2$ for which there exists continuous bijections $\;f: A \to B$ and $\;g: B\to A$.

I realize that $A$ and $B$ must be noncompact.

Since $A, B$ are closed $\; \Rightarrow \; A, B$ are unbounded. I am able to find $A,B\subset \mathbb R^2$ that are closed, unbounded, connected, and are not homeomorphic to each other, and then I'm stuck with the continuous bijections.

Found related examples [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/30661/non-homeomorphic-spaces-that-have-continuous-bijections-between-them), but don't see how to extend them to my question.

Comment: The same question was asked here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1623080/construct-nonhomeomorphic-connected-closed-subsets-a-b-subset-mathbbr2

Comment: but, that question is closed.

Comment: @aberdysh You should probably mention that this is a homework problem ;)

Answer (score 1):

We use the usual trick. Let

$$E_0=\big(\{0\}\times\Bbb R\big)\cup\big([0,1]\times\Bbb Z\big)\cup\big((1,2)\times\{0\}\big)\,.$$

To get $E_1$ from $E_0$, replace each line segment $[0,1]\times\{n\}$ for $n\in\Bbb Z^+$ by the closed line segment from $\langle 0,n\rangle$ to $\left\langle 2-\frac1n,1\right\rangle$. To get $E_2$ from $E_1$, replace each line segment $[0,1]\times\{-n\}$ for $n\in\Bbb Z^+$ by the closed line segment from $\langle 0,-n\rangle$ to $\left\langle 1-\frac1n,-1\right\rangle$. It is easily verified that the maps

$$f_0:E_0\to E_1:\langle x,y\rangle\mapsto\begin{cases}
\langle x,y\rangle,&\text{if }y\le 0\\
\left\langle x\left(2-\frac1y\right),y-x(y-1)\right\rangle,&\text{if }y>0
\end{cases}$$

and

$$g_0:E_1\to E_2:\langle x,y\rangle\mapsto\begin{cases}
\langle x,y\rangle,&\text{if }y\ge 0\\
\left\langle x\left(2+\frac1y\right),y+x(|y|-1)\right\rangle,&\text{if }y<0
\end{cases}$$

are continuous bijections.

For $A\subseteq\Bbb R^2$ and $\langle u,v\rangle\in\Bbb R$ let $A+\langle u,v\rangle=\{\langle x+u,y+v\rangle:\langle x,y\rangle\in A\}$ and let

$$X=\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb Z^+}(E_0-\langle 2n,0\rangle)\cup E_0\cup\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb Z^+}(E_2+\langle 2n,0\rangle)$$

and

$$Y=\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb Z^+}(E_0-\langle 2n,0\rangle)\cup E_1\cup\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb Z^+}(E_2+\langle 2n,0\rangle)\,;$$

the maps

$$F:X\to Y:\langle x,y\rangle\mapsto\begin{cases}
\langle x,y\rangle,&\text{if }x<0\text{ or }x\ge 2\\
f_0(\langle x,y\rangle),&\text{if }0\le x<2
\end{cases}$$

and

$$G:Y\to X:\langle x,y\rangle\mapsto\begin{cases}
\langle x+2,y\rangle,&\text{if }x<0\text{ or }x\ge 2\\
g_0(\langle x,y\rangle)+\langle 2,0\rangle,&\text{if }0\le x<2
\end{cases}$$

are then continuous bijections.

The spaces $X$ and $Y$ are path-connected and therefore connected, and both are closed subsets of $\Bbb R^2$. They are not, however, homeomorphic.

To see this, let

$$\begin{align*}
C_X&=\{\langle 2n,1\rangle:n\in\Bbb Z^+\}\cup\{\langle 2n,-1\rangle:n\in\Bbb Z^+\}\,,\\
C_Y&=C_X\setminus\{\langle 2,-1\rangle\}\,,\text{ and}\\
F&=\{\langle 2n,0\rangle:n\in\Bbb Z\}\,;
\end{align*}$$

$C_X$ is the set of points at which $X$ is not locally connected, $C_Y$ is the set of points at which $Y$ is not locally connected, and $F$ is the set of points $p$ such that $X\setminus\{p\}$ has exactly four path components. ($F$ is also the set of points $p$ such that $Y\setminus\{p\}$ has exactly four path components.) Let $\langle x,y\rangle\in C_X$; then $\langle x,-y\rangle\in C_X$, and the obvious path in $X$ from $\langle x,y\rangle$ to $\langle x,-y\rangle$ contains exactly one point of $F$, namely, $\langle x,0\rangle$. However, $\langle 2,1\rangle\in C_Y$, and every path in $Y$ from $\langle 2,1\rangle$ to another point of $C_Y$ contains at least two points of $F$. Thus, no point of $X$ can be the image of $\langle 2,1\rangle$ under a homeomorphism, and $X$ and $Y$ are not homeomorphic.